# template parameters for free functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-templates

I'm experimenting with template template parameters.
I have no problems to make them work with classes but for some reason it does not work with functions.

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B, C, D};

  template<class EnumType, template<EnumType> class Fun >
  class MyTest
    {
    }

    template<MyEnum myEnum>
      void freeFunc(int argument)
        {
        LOG_ERROR("  void freeFunc(int argument) default case!!! ");
        }

      template<>
      void freeFunc<MyEnum::A>(int argument); // implemented in cpp

      template<>
      void freeFunc<MyEnum::B>(int argument); // implemented in cpp

      template<>
      void freeFunc<MyEnum::C>(int argument); // implemented in cpp

      template<>
      void freeFunc<MyEnum::D>(int argument); // implemented in cpp


template<MyEnum s>
class Cde
  {
   public:
  };


  MyTest<MyEnum, Cde > test1; // does compile

  MyTest<MyEnum, freeFunc > test2; // does not compile
```

I don't understand why the test2 does not compile.  It just says:
 error:   expected a class template, got 'freeFunc'

What am I doing wrong?

[edit] what I'm looking for is a way to get a generic way to both get free functions and class template templatized on an enum class

Comment: Why would it compile? `freeFunc` does not match type `template<EnumType> class Fun`...

Comment: and why Cde does then? it seems the same kind of signature

Comment: @user3770392 Cde is a class

Comment: @user3770392: classes and functions are different...

Comment: that's for sure.. but as @songyuanyao said probably there's no way to use it for free functions..

Comment: You may turn your functions into functor class.

Comment: yes, that seems the only viable option :(

Answer (score 1):

Note that function templates can't be used as [template template argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments),

> A template argument for a template template parameter must be an id-expression which names a class template or a template alias.

Comment: damn it..  basically I'm stuck then :/